# Select hash from collection of hash based on subset of another hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Given I have hash:

```
Grp1:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
Grp2:
    key1: value4
    key2: value2
    key3: value5
```

and I have another hash:

```
 key1: value4
 key2: value2
```

I want to search in first set of hash and choose `Grp2' key1:value4` because `Grp2` matches the condition. How should I do that?

Note: I tried using the `select` command and tried some logic offered by referring documents. My intentions are not to get sample code but just a hint. Sorry if my question sounds like I am asking for code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us to write free code.

Comment: Free code is the only code I write, so I have no objection to offering some. Moreover, I know that Ruby newbies sometimes don't know where to start to solve a problem, so I do not insist that code be shown as evidence that the asker has attempted to solve the problem. (I am also mindful that high-rep askers are *never* asked to show their code.)

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to express the two hashes correctly, either as I have done in my answer or, if I am mistaken, how they should appear. It's also helpful to assign each one to a variable so that those giving answers or posting conments can simply refer to the variables without having to define them.

Comment: updated the hash which need to match with main hash to search.

Comment: rb, your hashes still need braces (`{`, `}`) and commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you refer to as your first hash is not hash. In fact, it's not a Ruby object of any kind. If it is to be a hash, you need to write it like this:

```
g = { :Grp1 => { key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3 },
      :Grp2 => { key1: value4, key2: value2, key3: value5 } }
```

Since the keys are all symbols, you could instead use the syntax:

```
g = { Grp1: { key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3 },
      Grp2: { key1: value4, key2: value2, key3: value5 } }
```

`value1` (and `value2` and so on) must be either a variable or a method, but you have not given us it's value (if it's a variable) or its return value is (if it's a method), so I will replace those variables or methods with literals:

```
g = { Grp1: { key1: 7, key2: 4, key3: 'cat' },
      Grp2: { key1: 1, key2: 3, key3: 'dog' } }
```

Your second hash:

```
h = { :key1 => value4, :key2 => value2 }
```

has the same problem, so I'll replace it with:

```
h = { :key1 => 1, :key2 => 3 }
```

which alternatively could be expressed:

```
h = { key1: 1, key2: 3 }
```

Assuming what I have written is correct, we can write a method as follows, using the methods [Hash#keys](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys), [Hash#key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F), [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) and [Enumerable#all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
def doit(g, h)
  hkeys = h.keys
  puts "hkeys=#{hkeys}"
  g.find do |k,v|
    puts "k=#{k}"
    puts "v=#{v}"
    hkeys.all? do |j|
      puts "  v.key?(#{j})=#{v.key?(j)}"
      puts "  v[#{j}]==#{h[j]}: #{v[j]==h[j]}"
      v.key?(j) && v[j] == h[j]
    end
  end
end
```

I've added some `puts` statements so you can see the results of the calculations. For `g` and `h` defined above (with literal values):

```
doit(g,h)  
hkeys=[:key1, :key2]
k=Grp1
v={:key1=>7, :key2=>4, :key3=>"cat"}
  v.key?(key1)=true
  v[key1]==1: false
k=Grp2
v={:key1=>1, :key2=>3, :key3=>"dog"}
  v.key?(key1)=true
  v[key1]==1: true
  v.key?(key2)=true
  v[key2]==3: true
  #=> [:Grp2, {:key1=>1, :key2=>3, :key3=>"dog"}]
```

After stripping out the `puts` statements and making one small change, I would write the method like this:

```
def doit(g, h)
  hkeys = h.keys
  g.find { |_,v| hkeys.all? { |j| v.key?(j) && v[j] == h[j] } }
end
```

The small change is that I've replaced the block variable `k` with the variable `_` to draw attention to the fact that I'm not using it in the block.

There are many ways to to write this method. Here's another, using the method [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
def doit(g, h)
  hkeys = h.keys
  hvalues = h.values
  g.find { |_,v| v.values_at(*hkeys) == hvalues }
end
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post section 1 and questions to 
aditya Kumar as comments to your own answer? Answers, just like questions, should be concise.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, thank you for your helpful suggestion. It seemed more fitting to post the comments on the question.

Comment: that was helpful. Thanks @CarySwoveland